# que solo máximo se pueda colocar el numero 45 - reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

buen dia, tengo un campo input numérico donde al darle en flechas del mismo campo me deja llegar hasta el numero 45 pero si coloco manual un numero mayor a 45 me lo esta dejando hacer.

Lo que necesito es que solo me permita escribir números que no sean mayor a 45 y que no sean menor a 0.

```js
import React from 'react'

function Pruebas(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <input type="number" placeholder="Minutos por tiempo" className="form-control"  min = "1" max= "45" 
   name="minutos_juegos"
   value={props.getState('minutos_juegos', '')} 
   onChange={props.handleChange} />
      
    </div>
  )
}

export default Pruebas
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te recomiendo pasar el valor de los minutos a un `useState`, y no aplicarlo directamente en el *value* del input. De esta manera, tienes más control sobre el estado, puedes utilizarlo en validaciones y además es más legible.

Dicho esto, entonces

```
const Pruebas = () => {      
  const [minutes, setMinutes] = useState(0)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (minutes && (+minutes < 0 || +minutes > 45)) setMinutes(0)
  }, [minutes])

  const handleChange = ({ target: { value } }) => setMinutes(value);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        type="number"
        placeholder="Minutos por tiempo"
        className="form-control"
        min="1"
        max="45"
        name="minutos_juegos"
        value={minutes}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

De esta manera, cada vez que el estado de *minutes* cambie, validará si el valor cumple la condición, y en caso de no hacerlo, lo setea a 0.

> PD: Simule los minutos como valor directo en el state, ya que
> ignoro que hace tu `getState()`, pero sería sólo ajustar eso.

Nos comentas

Comment: aparece un error señalando const [minutes, setMinutes] = useState(minutes), donde aparece el primer "minutes",  mensaje error "minutes' has already been declared"

Comment: Cambia el nombre del useState. Te da error por ambigüedad

Comment: ya agregue minutos como lo muestra en la posible solución pero ahora cuando coloco un valor mayor a 45 en el campo no hace nada , me esta dejando colocar cualquier valor mayor a 45

Comment: Ojo, que en la respuesta te coloque un _postdata_ Lo más probable es que como estás usando un getState para obtener los minutos, no te este funcionando por eso. Debes adaptar la respuesta a la forma en que tú la estás implementando, porque [acá](https://codesandbox.io/s/validacion-de-input-min-y-max-y6yte) funciona correctamente

Comment: estoy probando en un archivo independiente la respuesta y no esta funcionando

Comment: ya me funciono muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Podrías pasar el código completo? Con el state y el handleChange?

Podrías hacer en el handle un if, creo que en el onChange actualizas el state por lo que podrías poner un if, indicando que si el valor del state es mayor a 45 haga un set del state a 45, sino que haga un set del state pasándole el event.target.value.. podrías resolverlo dentro del mismo onChange con un operador ternario..

Aparentemente el handleChange lo estás recibiendo por props desde un componente padre, en el es que setearías lo que querés que pase al cambiar el valor del input..

Es necesario un poco más de info para entender lo que intentas hacer o como lo estás intentando.

Comment: no tengo nada en el handleChange .

Comment: como seria con el if ?

Comment: como seria con el if  o el operador ternario?